# Using OR in an if statement

Tags: ifelse

I have this code:

```
{if segment_1 != "slug1" || segment_1 != "slug2"}<h2>Text</h2>{/if}
```

For some reason this does not work with the second instruction after the OR operator. If I remove the OR operator and the following code it is fine ie.

```
{if segment_1 != "slug1"}<h2>Text</h2>{/if}
```

The OR operator seems to be the problem here. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: So just to clarify, the example of `{if segment_1 == "slug1|slug2"} instead of {if segment_1 == "slug1" OR segment_1 == "slug2"}` isn't correct, is that right?

Comment: @edward If the first snippet of code works for you, it's the equivalent of the second snippet, just shorthard. If the first one does not work, then use the second snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case here, because of the double "!=", use "AND" instead of "OR":

```
{if segment_1 != "slug1" AND segment_1 != "slug2"}<h2>Text</h2>{/if}
```

OR use:

```
{if segment_1 == "slug1" OR segment_1 == "slug2"}
{if:else}
    <h2>Text</h2>
{/if}
```

---

DOCS: [**Logical Operator**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#logical-operators)

Comment: I was thinking that by using AND both statements would need to be true in order for the <h2> to appear. I thought that OR made more sense. Have I got my thinking upside down and back to front?

Comment: Because both statements need to be true (segment_1 should not be "slug1" AND not be "slug2"), then AND is correct. Just to clarify, "AND" or "&&" are both valid operators, as is "OR" or "||".

Comment: You're welcome... Did my answer help solve your issue? If yes, select the answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Comment: Little known fact, you can actually do `{if segment_1 == "slug1|slug2"}` instead of `{if segment_1 == "slug1" OR segment_1 == "slug2"}`.

Comment: Not sure that this method with the pipe is still working as of ee5 -- it didn't work for me just now.

Comment: @edward EE5 supports using || instead of OR in conditionals... Info here in the docs: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/templates/conditionals.html#logical-operators

Comment: thanks for that update! I didn't anticipate it would change....

Comment: @edward Actually, are you saying that {if segment_1 == "slug1|slug2"} doesn't work for you in EE5?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I haven't tried the double pipe, but this version didn't work for me.

Comment: Actually, I just checked and the particular site I'm referring to is EE3.5, not EE5

Comment: @edward {if segment_1 == "XXX" || segment_1 == "XXX"} will work fine for all versions of EE or use {if segment_1 == "XXX" OR segment_1 == "XXX"}